# Difference in CSS rotate 359 vs rotate 360

Tags: css, css-transforms

I suppose this is more academic than anything but I have an element I'm setting up to infinite spin and in my CSS file I have to add this (yes, I have my `moz` and `webkit` declarations in there too but that's not relevant here)

```
@keyframes spin {
    from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

It seems odd not to set 360 here but it seems to work with 359. Is 360 simply equivalent to 0 or what? Trying to understand how this works and if there's a practical difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is used, because on an infinite animation if the end and start are the same then there would be a delay when starting the next cycle..

0 and 360 degrees having the same representation would each consume a step of the animation.

Comment: @Machavity, keep in mind that the 1deg difference would make sense if the animation is slow enough.. In general you want to calculate the number of steps and then subtract from the `to` degrees one full step worth of degrees. (*if this sentence makes sense..*)

Comment: I wanted to keep the question generic but I've been tinkering with [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/) and they used 359 in their rotate. They were the first I've seen to do so and I really wanted to know why. I hate to just do stuff without understanding the reasoning. This makes sense now.

Comment: After quite a bit of slow motion testing, your answer seems incorrect. `0` to `360deg` produces a perfectly smooth and complete rotation while `0` to `359` produces a jump of 1 degree. If this used to be a bug in any major browser, today, `0` to `360` appears to work as intended in Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 2):

**tldr:**

```
/********* CORRECT *********/

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

/********* NOT CORRECT *********/

@keyframes spin {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
```

**full explanation:**

The following syntaxes are equivalent and all produce a perfectly smooth and continuous infinite circular animation:

```
@keyframes spin-turn {
  from { transform: rotate(0turn); }
  to { transform: rotate(1turn); }
}
@keyframes spin-grad {
  from { transform: rotate(0grad); }
  to { transform: rotate(400grad); }
}
@keyframes spin-deg {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin-rad {
  from { transform: rotate(0rad); }
  to { transform: rotate(6.28318530718rad); } /* 2 × π */
}
```

Most importantly, ***there is no animation step in between*** `100%` and `0%`.

When transitioning between animation iterations, the frame corresponding to `100%` is not rendered. The browser uses its value to calculate all the intermediary frames up to it (their number depends on device refresh rate and browser rendering engine, not on the CSS unit used). When the next animation iteration exists, the frame corresponding to `100%` is replaced by the first frame of the next iteration (the `0%` one).
The `100%` frame is only rendered when `animation-iteration-count` is a positive finite number, after all iteration counts have been played. In other words, when the animation has stopped.

---

Thus, using `to: { transform: rotate(359deg); }` produces a jump forward in the animation of exactly `1deg`. It's a jump equal to `0.2(7)%` of a full turn and is therefore hardly noticeable when the animated element is small or when the speed of animation is relatively fast.

Here's a tool to compare the different syntaxes. The jump forward can be observed at the top position (when the radar line reaches the north point of the circle), with `deg-359` animation syntax selected, with an animation duration above 10 seconds.

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: () => ({
    units: ['turn', 'grad', 'rad', 'deg', 'deg-359'],
    animation: 'spin-deg-359',
    duration: 18
  }),
  computed: {
    rotatorStyle() {
      return {
        animation: `${this.animation} ${this.duration}s linear infinite`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
.controls > div {
  display: flex;
  padding: 3px 0;
}
.controls {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.controls label {
  width: 80px;
}
input[type="number"] {
  width: 73px;
}
#app {
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 1rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.ratio {
  display: grid;
  width: calc(100vh - 2rem);
}
@media(max-width: 767.98px) {
  #app {
    flex-direction: column;
    height: auto;
  }
  .ratio {
    width: 100%;
    flex: 0 0 auto;
  }
}
.ratio > * {
  grid-area: 1/1;
}
.rotator {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  position: relative;
}
.rotator:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  width: 50%;
  height: 0;
  top: 50%;
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}

@keyframes spin-deg {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}
@keyframes spin-deg-359 {
  from { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  to { transform: rotate(359deg); }
}
@keyframes spin-rad {
  from { transform: rotate(0rad); }
  to { transform: rotate(6.28318530718rad); }
}
@keyframes spin-turn {
  from { transform: rotate(0turn); }
  to { transform: rotate(1turn); }
}
@keyframes spin-grad {
  from { transform: rotate(0grad); }
  to { transform: rotate(400grad); }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div class="controls">
    <div>
      <label for="duration">duration</label>
      <input id="duration" v-model="duration" type="number">s
    </div>
    <div>
      <label for="animation">animation</label>
      <select id="animation" v-model="animation">
        <option v-for="unit in units" :key="unit" :value="'spin-' + unit">{{unit}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>    
  </div>
  <div class="ratio">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 1 1"></svg>
    <div class="rotator"
       :style="rotatorStyle"></div>
   </div>
  
</div>
```

The jump becomes more noticeable as you increase the screen size (full-page mode) or as you increase the animation-duration (i.e: `30s`).

Answer (score 1):

360 is 0, there are 360 degrees in a circle. So 360 would take you full circle, back to 0.